# Trying to get property 'photo' of non-object - Laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel

Can anyone please help me with this, I am unable to get the exact path of the files from storage to my mail attachment in my mailable dynamically in a way that every new user during the registration process can upload their images and that can be sent as an attachment to a mail address, this is my registration controller - RegisterController.php

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

use App\Mail\RegisterMail;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    use RegistersUsers;
    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        ]);
    }
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);

        if (request()->hasFile('photo')){
            $photo = request()->file('photo')->getClientOriginalName();
            request()->file('photo')->storeAs('photos', $user->id. '/' . $photo, '');
            $user->update(['photo' => $photo]);
        }

        if (request()->hasFile('signature')){
            $signature = request()->file('signature')->getClientOriginalName();
            request()->file('signature')->storeAs('signatures', $user->id. '/' . $signature, '');
            $user->update(['signature' => $signature]);
        }


        Mail::to('test@test.com')->send(new RegisterMail($data));

        return $user;
    }
}
```

My Mailable - RegisterMail.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class RegisterMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;
    public $data;

    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function build()
    {
        $attachments = [
            'storage/photos/'.auth()->id().'/'.auth()->user()->photo->photo,
            'storage/signatures/'.auth()->id().'/'.auth()->user()->signature->signature,
        ];

        $email = $this->subject('New Registration')->view('my_mail_template')->with('data', $this->data);

        foreach($attachments as $filePath){
            $email->attach($filePath);
        }
        return $email;
    }
}
```

My Migration

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('photo')->nullable();
            $table->string('signature')->nullable();
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

My Model - User.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'photo', 'signature',
    ];


    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

My Route - web.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

Comment: Can you clarify which part of your code is Throwing an error? The error in your title tells you that the either ->user()->photo or user() is not an object, did you try to work with that?

Comment: @Jeroen I think its user() that is throwing the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this `auth()->user()->photo->photo` to this `auth()->user()->photo` in your `class RegisterMail`.

`photo` on your `User` model is a field, not a relationship to another model. The second `->photo` in your code is trying to access a property on what is probably a string.

Comment: thanks for you answer, I tried that, still getting same error

Comment: Perhaps what you're looking for is `Auth::user()->photo`

Comment: I tried, 'storage/photos/'.Auth::id().'/'.Auth::user()->photo, and 'storage/photos/'.auth()->id().'/'.Auth::user()->photo, still no effect, same error. if I add a direct path to the image like 'storage/photos/1/image.jpg', it works, but when i try to fetch it dynamically it doesn't work.

Comment: I've cleared cache, I've cleared views, nothing happens, same error.

Comment: You'll need to change all your `auth()->user()`s to `Auth::user()`, and change `auth()->user()->signature->signature` to `Auth::user()->signature`

Comment: I did that, but now I am getting error **Trying to get property 'id' of non-object.** I used these lines `'storage/photos/'.Auth::user()->id.'/'.Auth::user()->photo` and `'storage/signatures/'.Auth::user()->id.'/'.Auth::user()->signature,`

Comment: You're using `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;`, and you're authenticated, right?

Comment: Yes I am using it, and what do u mean by authenticated, I mean email verification link is sent but user data is stored in the database before user email is verified.

Comment: I mean logged in to your application

Comment: `Auth::user()` will only return an object if you're authenticated (i.e. if you're logged in)

Comment: The image files have to be sent right after the user submits registration form, so if not Auth then what else should I use?

Comment: Your user isn't authenticated when the email is sent to them. That's why `Auth::user()` is not returning a user, and why your code's not working.

Comment: Either authenticate them before sending the email, or pass the relevant user to your `Mailable`

Comment: Can you please tell me how do I achieve that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Auth::attempt([ "email" => EMAILHERE, "password" => PASSWORDHERE ]);`

Comment: Really, you should read the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/authentication) on it too.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Joundill, you helped me achieve this, finally. You are a savior.

Comment: Hahah, took long enough, aye? :)